# NSTableView Drawing Count

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mountain-lion, nstableview

I have two tables (**NSTableView**) on a window.  Well, the number is irrelevant.  Anyway, the source of the first table (tableView1) is **NSMutableArray** with **NSMutableDictionary**.  And I have the following code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView {
    if (aTableView == tableView1) {
        return [itemArray1 count];
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

- tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)TableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    // tableView1
    if (aTableView == tableView1) {
        NSString *foldername = [[itemArray1 objectAtIndex:rowIndex] objectForKey:key1a];
        NSString *count = [[itemArray1 objectAtIndex:rowIndex] objectForKey:key1c];
        if ([[TableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"folder"]) {
            return foldername;
        }

        if([[TableColumn identifier] isEqualTo:@"count"]){
            return count;
        }

        else {
            return @"";
        }

    // tableView2
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

I get what I want, and the second column shows the number of items (count).  I wonder how I can possibly draw this number like the **SidebarDemo** example project?  (Shown at the bottom...)  This project utilizes - (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item to show a static number (42).  Can I show the number like that with NSTableView as well?  I could just draw a circled number if it were an iOS application.

Thank you for your advice.

[image]

Comment: All righty.  I got it by actually drawing a rounded rectangle with numbers just as I do with iOS apps.

Answer (score 1):

tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: (NSTableViewDelegate) should work similar.

Comment: What for? -tableView:… works as outlineView:…, but takes (of course) an instance of table view instead of outline and a row instead of an item as parameters. This 1:1. The content of the method can be c&p'ed from the sample.